# JQuery: Preserving Line Breaks with var text split?

Tags: jquery, html, text, var

I'm very new to jquery, so excuse me if the answer is elsewhere. I've been trying to figure out how to preserve `<br>` line breaks in jQuery-affected text. I've found solutions involving replacing `<br>` with `\n`. However, this deactivates the code I'm using to split text.

Is there any way for me to show line breaks with a code like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/471/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text() in jQuery returns the Visible text, not the html. Use html() instead of text() while fetching the content of "p".

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` method would fetch you just the text inside the element, not the corresponding html. You need to use `html()` to get all contents including the text.

Replace this :

```
var text = p.text().split(' ');
```

with :

```
var text = p.html().split(' ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fz39N/473/

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. Accept the answer if that was the only issue you had. Thanks